# Python Higher order-function with varying arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x, higher-order-functions

I am trying to write a higher-order function that takes a varying amount of arguments.
For instance something like this

```
def higher(fnc, args):
    print(f"Calling function {fnc}")
    fnc(argv)

def one_arg(only_arg):
    print(f"Here is the only arg {only}")

def two_arg(first, second):
    print(f"Here is the first {first} And here is the second {second}")

higher(one_arg, "Only one argument")
higher(two_arg, "Here's one arg", "and Another one")
```

Is it possible to do this without changing the functions one_arg() or two_arg() ?

I've looked into using ***argv** but I don't think I understand it well enough or see a way to use that without changing those two functions

Answer (score 1):

you can just use * to define multiple args.

```py
def higher(fnc, *args):
    print(f"Calling function {fnc}")
    fnc(*args)

def one_arg(only_arg):
    print(f"Here is the only arg {only_arg}")

def two_arg(first, second):
    print(f"Here is the first {first} And here is the second {second}")

higher(one_arg, "Only one argument")
higher(two_arg, "Here's one arg", "and Another one")
```

Also for more details regarding functions and object oriented programming in python you can refer to this [link](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_functions.asp)

There are a lot more additional resources available online for you to learn

Comment: Didn't realize there was such an elegant solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Define `higher` and call `fnc` like this:

```
def higher(fnc, *args):
    print(f"Calling function {fnc}")
    fnc(*args)
```

Within the body of `higher`, `args` is a tuple of the positional arguments passed after `fnc`.  Calling `fnc(*args)` spreads that tuple into individual positional arguments *to* `fnc`.